# appium findElement returns result from neighbour nodes

Tags: android, appium

I am having some issues with findElement being used on a WebElement.

I have a RecyclerView filled with RelativeLayouts, when I try to use findElement(By.id()) on the RelativeLayout marked with "1" in [uiautomationviewer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swKvO.png) it returns the element marked with "2".

What I am trying to do is determined if the element marked with "2" is present in any of the RelativeLayouts.

I also tried using findElements.size() == 0, but I get the same result. findElements has size == 1 even though the RelativeLayout does not contain the element.

I noticed that each time I search for the element it searches all neighbour nodes and returns the first occurrence.

Am I wrong on how I expect findElement to work when used on a WebElement? If not, does anyone have any ideas what causes this behaviour?

Using:
java 1.8.0_31
appium v1.4.8
appium java client 3.3.0

tried this on android 4.4.2 and 5.0

Comment: As you  have mentioned your views are in Recycler view , your FrameLayout, ImageView ,checkbox might have the same id in all Relative layout. Is it the case ? If yes then you should prefer xpath.

Comment: The id I am searching for is the same for each imageview in each layout, but when I check the element that is returned (by coordinates) it is located in a different relative layout. In the code the image view is present in all relative layouts, but in some it has it's visibility set to GONE, but when I check these it return from the other layout.

Comment: Okay . Then you must go for xpath . Do not use id .

Comment: Xpath does not work in my case because I get the following error: "Original error: Cannot use xpath locator strategy from an element. It can only be used from the root element". Right now the only solution I see is using xpath from driver, but that looks messy and I was trying to avoid it.

Comment: Are you trying to get Imageview count or Relative layout count  ? or if you want count of child Rview you can use following code : List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.id("Rview_id"));
int count = list.count;
WebElement element = list.get(0);

Comment: I want to get the list of relative layouts that do not have the Imageview element with that ID as a child.

In the end I was able to get a workaround by asking the dev team to add content-desc to the relative layout so I can differentiate it like that, but the original issue still persists.